# Trouble creating plain old ruby objects in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I'm trying to make a fantasy football website that lets users enter settings for their league and receive recommendations for available players.  I've created a plain old ruby object "Draft" that has the logic for picking the best players.  I'm trying to create a new draft for each visitor based on the settings they enter but I can't figure out how to get the controller to make a new ruby instance with the unique settings.

I'm trying to render a form for the draft object so that after the user selects the draft settings, the draft will start and the suggestions will show.

I've got the root set to #new so that a new draft can be created.  I try to render a form but the controller throws the error: "param is missing or the value is empty: draft".

Here is what my controller looks like:

```
def new
    @draft = Draft.new(draft_params)
end

private

  def draft_params
    params.require(:draft).permit(:draft_type, :number_of_teams)
  end
```

The params are properly linked in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@draft) do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :draft_type %>
    <%= f.text_field :draft_type, :class => 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :number_of_teams %>
    <%= f.number_field , :class => 'form-control', %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-info' %>

<% end %>
```

How can I get my new draft to properly show? 
Please help me find what I'm doing wrong!!

Here's the github repo if you want to see more:
https://github.com/Cheex11/drafter

Comment: Interesting - I've never done a non-ActiveRecord model before. I'd love to hear how you get this working - how are you persisting the `Draft` data between states?

Answer (score 0):

You require `draft` parameter, but it is not in the form (only `draft_type` text field and `number_of_teams` number field are). Add another form control for the `draft` parameter, or don't require it. (Or, I suppose, inject it from session or whatever.)

EDIT: looking at your github code,

```
def initialize(number_of_teams, draft_type)
```

your model only includes the two parameters; why `.require(:draft)`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!  I added the require draft because I was just following what someone else did in an example I found.  I removed the require and just have the permit now.  Unfortunately, it now gives the error: "  SyntaxError at / or '[' or '.'  "

Thank you so much for your response.  I'm going to continue to try to get around this problem.

Comment: Surely the `form_for` method would create the `draft` key in the params? Or perhaps I'm confused for not using an ActiveRecord `model`